# D3.js how to create this zoom behavior?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I want my chart's xAxis to behave like this when zooming using mousewheel.
Expected behavior: [image: Expected behavior]

My current zoom

```
const zoomExtent = [ [ 0, 0 ], [ innerWidth, innerHeight ] ]
const xScale = scaleUtc().domain(minMaxData).range([0, innerWidth])

const handleZoom  = ({ transform }) => {
  transform.rescaleX(xScale)
}

const zoomBehavior = zoom().scaleExtent([ 0.4, 4 ]).extent(zoomExtent).translateExtent(zoomExtent).on('zoom', handleZoom)
```

This is my chart with d3 default behavior
[image: with d3 default behavior]

My questions:

1. How to always focus the zoom to the right edges (the latest data on the chart) instead of where the mouse currently at?
2. How to prevent x axis from expanding to the right that causing my latest data (at the right edge) to leave the view port ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an elegant solution but it worked.

```
// check if wheeled
const isWheeled = sourceEvent.type === 'wheel'

// i need it to be infinite because i lazy load the older data.
// there is no middle infinity.
const zoomExtent = [ [ Infinity, 0 ], [ innerWidth, innerHeight ] ]

// fix focal point at the innerwidth. using previous transform
const tx = innerWidth - transform.invertX(innerWidth) * k
const myZoom = zoomIdentity.translate(isWheeled ? tx : x, 0).scale(k)

// prevent jumping when dragging
sourceEvent.target.__zoom = myZoom

// update scale
const handleZoom  = ({ transform }) => {
  myZoom.rescaleX(xScale)
}
```

If you have better solution pls let me know.